# How to check the status of a cudastream before/after create/destroy?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have the following code:

```
cudaStream_t stream
.... // How to check status of stream before create
cudaStreamCreate(&stream)
.... // How to check status of stream after create
cudaStreamDestroy(stream)
.... // How to check status of stream after destroy
```

I want the check the status at each of the sync points and see the different statuses.

Comment: There is no stream to check status of before it is created or after it is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't check the status of something that does not exist, so it doesn't make sense to check before creation or after destruction.

After creation, the best function is [cudaStreamQuery](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g2021adeb17905c7ec2a3c1bf125c5435). This will tell you if all the operations in the stream have completed, and will also return any asynchronous errors that may have occurred during stream execution.

Comment: Hmm the cudastream_t object exists on the stack before and after create and destroy api calls. It might be valid to have a status e.g. not initialized or destroyed